# XBMC compile error under Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, kodi

I was trying to compile xbmc under Raspbian following [these instructions](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianXBMC).

However, when I call the main `make`, I got a compile error on `xbmc.bin`:

> member xbmc/guilib/guilib.a(GUIPanelContainer.o) in archive is not an object

Any help?
Anyone got this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I know, this doesn't actually answer to your question, but instead of compiling yourself, have you considered using a XBMC-dedicated distribution built on top of Rasbpian, namely [Raspbmc](http://www.raspbmc.com/) or [Xbian](http://xbian.org/)?

Comment: Can you explain the difference between Xbian and Raspbmc please?

Comment: Some may consider this a bit delicate subject. Those are two separate projects both aiming for same goal, offer a pre-built XBMC Media Center for RPi. Unfortunately the projects have not joined forces, but ended up competing with each other instead.
The Raspbmc has been a bit longer around and it may have a bit larger community behind. I have used only that and can say that at least it works really well and is extremely easy to set-up and use.
And to not forget, [OpenELEC](http://openelec.tv/) is the third choice offering about the same. It is a multi-platform project though not only for RPi.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks. I'm currently using Raspbmc, it does what I need it to do. The biggest difference I see, is the prepackaged Usenet tools in Xbian. My server handles all that for me, so not enough reason for me to change. 
Core functionality and performance wise, are they all equal?

Comment: As said, I have not used Xbian, but the the core functionality should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the glitch:
I had to download the whole package directly under the filesystem root.

After that, everything works fine.